# jquery: remove appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following code:

```
$.each(pk2, function(i,value) {   
     $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", i+1)
         .text(value)); 

  });
```

My problem is that overtime this code is called, new elements are kept on being appended. What I need to do is to clean  `$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2')` (remove appended staff) every time this code is called.

I have tried `$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').remove()` but it removes the whole div structure.
`$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').val('')` is doing nothing as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.empty()` it will only remove the children not structure.

```
$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

[remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) accepts `selector` which filters the element to be removed.

```
   $.each(pk2, function(i,value) {   
       var el = $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2');
       el.remove('option');
       el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i+1).text(value)); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Empty `$('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2').empty()` instead of remove(). empty will clear the child elements not the element itself. https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Moreover you can use the concept of flag if you don't want to append elements again and again

```
var flag=true;
$.each(pk2, function(i,value) { 
  if(flag){
     $('#query_form_opt_'+cell+'_2')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", i+1)
         .text(value)); 
   }
   flag=false

  });
```